# Inner class private member access and enclosing's friendness

Tags: c++, c++14, inner-classes, friend

I am trying to figure out how to make a `private/protected` member of an inner type accessible to its enclosing class.

My search led me to many questions about how to access an *enclosing member* from the inner class ([e.g.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5013717/are-inner-classes-in-c-automatically-friends?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)) but this is not what I need. Many other posts traverse Java, and this is definitely not what I need. This is C++.

Consider this MCVE:

```
#include <iostream>

struct bla
{
    bla( );
    ~bla( );

    class inner;

    inner *_inner;
};

class bla::inner
{
public:
    inner( )
    :   field( 13 )
    {}

private:
    friend struct bla;

    unsigned field;
};


bla::bla( )
:   _inner( new inner )
{}

bla::~bla( )
{
    delete _inner;
}

int main( )
{
    bla _bla;
    _bla._inner->field = 42;
    std::cout << "bla::_inner->field: " << _bla._inner->field << std::endl;
}
```

[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0b3e86b28287f61d)

The only question I could find out treating what I need is [C++ Outer class access Inner class's private - why forbidden](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36008654/c-outer-class-access-inner-classs-private-why-forbidden), but the proposed solution does not work for me:

```
$ g++ -std=c++14 -Wall inner_class.cpp -o inner_class
inner_class.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
inner_class.cpp:23:11: error: ‘unsigned int bla::inner::field’ is private
  unsigned field;
           ^
inner_class.cpp:39:15: error: within this context
  _bla._inner->field = 42;
               ^
inner_class.cpp:23:11: error: ‘unsigned int bla::inner::field’ is private
  unsigned field;
           ^
inner_class.cpp:40:54: error: within this context
  std::cout << "bla::_inner->field: " << _bla._inner->field << std::endl;
```

How to properly give `bla` access to `field`? Did I miss any silly detail?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can't. Not in the context of `main` anyway. `main` has no access to private or protected fields, there's no way around that.

Comment: "but the proposed solution does not work for me:"  This would be the line that suggests this is an XY problem.  I would suggest you rewind a thought processes or two and say what the issue is that you're trying to solve.

Comment: @SombreroChicken I think you nailed it. I have just revised my code and found out that I must provide accessors to my "field" in "bla". Please post an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: @SombreroChicken " main has no access to private or protected fields, there's no way around that" - yes there is: `friend int main();` (Im not saying you *should* do it, just that you *could*)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't.

You seem to think that because `_bla` is an object of `bla` and `bla` is the outer class that you can access private fields of `inner` outside of `bla`. This is not the case.

Access modifiers work on scope, not on the objects you're operating on. You can access the private fields of `inner` in the class body of `bla` (in its methods etc). Not outside of it.

Answer (score 4):

Your code is correctly granting the friendship required for `bla` to access the private members of `bla::inner`. However, your problem is that you're not accessing the private member in `bla` (which would have access), you're accessing it in `main`, which of course has no access.

If you want `bla` to be able to access `bla::inner::field`, you need to give `bla` some functions for accessing it. Example:

```
struct bla
{
    bla( );
    ~bla( );

    class inner;

    inner *_inner;

    void setInnerField(int val) { _inner->field = val; }
};

// The rest as before

int main( )
{
    bla _bla;
    _bla.setInnerField(42);
    std::cout << "bla::_inner->field: " << _bla._inner->field << std::endl;
}
```

If, on the other hand, you want to give all outside code (such as `main`) access to the field, just make it public.

Comment: Thank you very much @Angew. Of course I also need an accessor to read `field` back. I apologise but Sombrero Chicken's response came first, so I think it is fair to consider his response. Thank you again.

Answer (score 2):

Making main as friend of bla::inner should work.

```
    class bla::inner
{
public:
    inner( )
    :   field( 13 )
    {}

private:
    friend struct bla;
    friend int main(); // Make main friend of bla
    unsigned field;
};
```

Comment: Well, technically I believe it indeed works but is not that beautiful. Other responses make it cleaner. Thanks.